# Node.js and Express, data.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting an error pushing newTask to allTasks, with the error being `TypeError: allTasks.push is not a function`

`data` is the JSON data pulled from a file using `fs`

```
var allTasks = JSON.parse(data);
var newTask = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: "BAM",
    description: "BOOM",
    image: "SLAM"
};
allTasks.push(newTask);
```

I've tried declaring `allTasks` as an array before parsing JSON But that didn't work either.

data.json is:

```
{
  "tasks": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "something",
    "description": "do some shit",
    "image": "image URL1"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "something2",
    "description": "do some shit2",
    "image": "image URL2"
  }]
}
```

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what `data` looks like. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: allTasks is a object not an array

Comment: `allTasks.tasks.push(newTask);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` after being parsed from a JSON string is an object, hence why `.push` isn't working.

It looks like what you want to do is `allTasks.tasks.push(newTask);`

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
    console.log("typeof allTasks: " + (typeof allTasks));
```

What does it display?  If it shows an object then try:

```
    console.log("typeof allTasks.push: " + (typeof allTasks['push']));
```

That should display function, if it doesn't then thats your problem, allTasks isn't an array.

Looking at your edit, I think what you need is:

```
    allTasks["tasks"].push(newTask);
```